# Nginx configuration not updating for browser

Tags: nginx

I am trying to serve a website with nginx. I have noticed that when I make changes to my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/game`, run `sudo service nginx restart`, it is not reflected when I try to pull it up in the browser.

The browser just hangs and waits for a response and then timesout.

However, it works perfectly fine if I try to do a curl request to my site on the command line. I get the normal nginx html basic file. Why is that? Here. (and yes, I have made a soft link from sites-enabled/game to sites-available/game)

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name my.site.uw.edu;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

}
```

Also, I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I don't think this version of Linux uses SELinux, but could this be some sort of security configuration related deal? I have had trouble in the past with SELinux when deploying on CentOS machines.

Comment: Possibly a caching issue?  Did you try to reload the page, [bypassing the cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)?

Comment: wow, yeah I cleared the cache and it worked. So once other people start viewing the site, how do I make changes to my nginx server and still have it reflected on the client end? Honestly I don't anticipate changing the nginx configuration ever, but just in case the situation arises

Comment: [Making sure a web page is not cached](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49547/2425163) (doesn't handle nginx, but should not be too different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable adding or modifying of “Expires” and “Cache-Control” response header using `expires` param:

```
expires off;
```

[nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires)

Comment: actually I am still getting the same issue when i try to redirect 80 to 443

Comment: Could you show full nginx config with redirect rules? Try to use snippet bellow for redirect:  server {
    server_name  yourdomain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

Comment: yeah I had that. I finally found it was an iptables issues. The server had some some strict configuration that I was not aware of. Good thinking though